# Django import Error(from extras.plugins import PluginConfig)

Tags: python, django, plugins

I'm new to Django and I try to develope a plugin for NextBox using this framework. To get familliar with it I'm using documentation from NextBox for this. My Problem is that I try to import a class as shown in the tutorial I get an Error that the package is unkown. When I want to install the package via PyCharm it seems to be the wrong one. Maybe someone of you can help me?

Doc: https://netbox.readthedocs.io/en/stable/plugins/development/

```
from extras.plugins import PluginConfig

class NextBoxUIConfig(PluginConfig):
```

In the IDE it says that extras is unkown after installing the package, .plugins is unkown as well as PluginConfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution is that the plugin has to be installed using `$ python setup.py develop` for development purposes. To install the plugin is necessary to have local netbox version installed. After using the command the name of the plugin has to be added to the netbox file `configuration.py`:

```
PLUGINS = [
    'plugin_name',
]
```

But be sure to use the same venv you use to run netbox when installing the plugin with the listed command. After that the IDE will probably say it doesn't know what `extras.something` is. But it's installed and netbox will recognize when the plugin uses some netbox specific classes.
For more information use the netbox documentation:
https://netbox.readthedocs.io/en/stable/plugins/